# Sudo makemap permission denied

Tags: centos, permissions, centos7, sudo

I'm trying to use the `makemap hash` command, but even as root it says **Permission denied**.
Command i'm trying to run:

```
sudo makemap hash /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth < /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth
-bash: /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth: Permission denied
```

Comment: The same reason you have difficulty with `sudo` and output redirection happens with input redirection `<` and `<<`, it is effected by the shell of the user calling sudo, not by `sudo`.

Comment: `sudo /bin/su -c "makemap hash /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth < /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth"`

Comment: @HBruijn Thanks please post that as answer and i'll validate.

Comment: Please vote up on the answer(s) to to duplicate question.

Comment: sudo /bin/su -c "makemap hash /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth < /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth"
makemap: error opening type hash map /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth: Permission denied. That comment and solutions within the duplicate question no longer apply. (For me at least).

Comment: Fixed it by temporarily owning the entire mail directory after being a bit ticked. sudo chown -R root /etc/mail
do the do with the hash making...
sudo chown -R smmta /etc/mail